# C# Why are my variables not carrying over properly between forms?

Tags: c#, forms, ms-access, listbox

I've got several forms, some of which rely on information between each form. In this case, the selected index of the chosen option in `Form 2` (AKA testSelect) is key to determining what will happen in `Form 3` (AKA testPresent). This is placed into an integer called `index`. Upon closing `form 2` the value of `index` is definitely whatever the `selectedindex` of the listbox is.

However upon opening and applying it in `form 3` it resets to 0 all the time, and I can't figure out why. below is the code where `index` is used/determined in `form 2` as well as the code where it is called in `form 3`. Also, it is a public int defined at the start of `form 2`;

```
     private void lstExams_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a connection object to the DB via string location
            con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            //Open the connection to the DB
            con.Open();

            String sql = "SELECT typeID, description FROM TestConfiguration WHERE examID = " +(lstExams.SelectedIndex +1);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable testConfig = new DataTable();
            //Set the SQL command text

            da.Fill(testConfig);
            lstTestType.DisplayMember = "description";
            lstTestType.ValueMember = "typeID";

            lstTestType.DataSource = testConfig;

            index = lstExams.SelectedIndex + 1;

            MessageBox.Show("INDEX = " + index);

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //If cannot connect to DB, display the error;
            MessageBox.Show("A Database error has occurred: " + Environment.NewLine + err.Message);
        }
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //var testPresent = new testPresent(this);

        testPresent testForm = new testPresent();
        testForm.Show();


        //testForm.difficulty = lstTestType.ValueMember;
        this.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("INDEX IS " + index);
        testForm.eID = (index);


    }
```

And for `form 3`

```
    public partial class testPresent : Form
{
    public int eID = 0;
    public String difficulty;
    testSelect select = new testSelect();


    //Get the connection path to the DB from the static class
    String connectionString = staticConnectionString.connectionString;
    //Declare connection object
    OleDbConnection con;

    public testPresent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void testPresent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            int qID;
            Random random = new Random();
            int examID;
            bool valid = false;
            String theQuestion;

            eID += select.index;

            //Create a connection object to the DB via string location
            con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            //Open the connection to the DB
            con.Open();

            MessageBox.Show("eID = " + select.index);

            if (eID == 1)
            {
                ...

            } 

            if (eID == 2)
            {
                ...

            } 

            if (eID == 3)
            {
                ...

            }



        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //If cannot connect to DB, display the error;
            MessageBox.Show("A Database error has occurred: " + Environment.NewLine + err.Message);
        }
    }
```

Oh yeah, this also uses Microsoft Access Databases to populate the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You set the value:

```
testForm.eID = (index);
```

But you do so *after* the form has already been loaded, so `testPresent_Load` has *already* used its default value:

```
testPresent testForm = new testPresent();
testForm.Show();  // this is where it uses the value
// ...
testForm.eID = (index);  // this is where you set it
```

If the value is required for the `testPresent` form entirely, and it needs the value right away, try including the value in the constructor:

```
public testPresent(int eid)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    eID = eid;
}
```

Then when you create an instance of the form you'd have to pass it that value:

```
testPresent testForm = new testPresent(index);
testForm.Show();
```

At that point there'd be no need to set the value externally, so it should be private.  (Data members should be private on objects anyway.):

```
private int eID;
```